# Why passing an inline list into println method isn't working in Groovy? (like 'println [1, 2, 3]')

Tags: groovy

Please explain why the following

```
println([1, 2, 3])
```

works in Groovy. And why the following

```
println [1, 2, 3]
```

fails with

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: println for class: main
    at main.run(main.groovy:2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Groovy sees an expression `identifier[index]` as a syntatic sugar to `identifier.getAt(index)` which takes precedence over a `identifier([index])`. So it is trying to treat `println` as a variable and getting `[1, 2, 3]` from it.