# Groovy function call omiting the parentheses

Tags: groovy, gradle

According to the [gradle documentation/section 13.5.2](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#N10B52) we can omit parentheses in a method call:

> Parentheses are optional for method calls.

But it seems it doesn't work when we try to apply the java plugin. If a script contains the following line:

```
apply [plugin: 'java']
```

We'll get the error:

```
 Maybe something should be set in parentheses or a comma is missing?
 @ line 1, column 8.
     apply [plugin: 'java']
            ^
```

But if we put this `Map`-literal into a parentheses it'll work fine.

```
apply([plugin: 'java'])
```

So we can't omit the parentheses when the argument is a `Map`, can we?

Comment: In this particular case `apply plugin:'java'` would work without the square brackets. "Named parameters" like this are automatically packed into a map.

Comment: Regarding `method bracket value bracket`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784622/why-passing-an-inline-list-into-println-method-isnt-working-in-groovy-like-p/23784939#23784939

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the specification says, parentheses can be omitted ***when there is no ambiguity***. I suspect the ambiguity in this case arises because the statement without parentheses looks a lot like array index syntax and the parser has trouble working out whether you are calling a method named 'apply' or trying to do something with an array named 'apply'.

Personally, this is why I tend to always use parentheses - if the parser can't work it out I'm sure another programmer reading the code won't either.

Comment: "_if the parser can't work it out I'm sure another programmer reading the code won't either._" -- Sums it up perfectly

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that the usual syntax of an array or map in Groovy uses brackets (for example, for empty ones you typically write `[]` or `[:]`, respectively), **the same bracket symbols are interpreted as the index operator if it follows an identifier**. Then Groovy tries to interpret `apply` as a property of the Gradle project, even if it does not exist. Groovy, as a dynamic language, allows us to define properties dynamically, so there is not always a way to tell at compile time if a property is going to exist. While it is questionable if that is a good design or not, Gradle's [`ExtraPropertiesExtension`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) very much makes use of this dynamic nature in Groovy for convenience. If you prefer more strict typing, I suggest you **try the Kotlin DSL**, which has much less of this kind of problems (I do not think it is completely gone, as we can still explicitly declare variables as [dynamic type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/dynamic-type.html)).

On the other hand, **one purpose of a DSL is to be concise and remove useless ceremony**. That is one thing Groovy excels at, because if the only parameter you need to pass to a method or closure is just an array or a map, you can just omit all kinds of brackets: `apply plugin: 'java'`. (Anything more complex than that is questionable for a DSL.)

And that is why I think that adding parentheses all the time (e.g., `apply([plugin: 'java'])`) to everywhere is not the right approach to [build scripts whose code is supposed to look declarative](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/authoring_maintainable_build_scripts.html#sec:avoid_imperative_logic_in_scripts) and to support that, very DSL like, at least not if you use Groovy, which was designed exactly for that purpose. Never using a language feature, even where it might have an advantage, is what lead to books like [Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742), where the author recommends we always use semicolons, and that is one of the most argued practices on the Internet, e.g. disagreed by the [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/). I personally think that it is more important to know the language you work with and e.g., know when a semicolon is needed, in general to produce the best quality code. The semicolon example may admittedly not be such a strong example for other than reducing ceremony. But **just because a language feature can be misused, it does not mean we should ban its use.** A kitchen knife is not bad just because we can hurt people with it. And the same can be told about Kotlin's most judged features.

Although nowadays we got **[the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block), which is the preferred way of loading plugins** (even if plugins are put in `buildSrc`, which will just need [some metadata definition](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#behind_the_scenes)), this question may still be relevant for the following reasons:

- programmatically applying plugins, e.g. `subprojects { apply plugin: 'java' }`,
- including custom build scripts using a similar syntax: `apply from: 'myscript.gradle'`,
- and maybe also if for some reason you can only refer to a plugin by its class name.

Therefore the question is still valid.